# Sendkeys not working in protractor because of "selenium webdriver promise defer error"

Tags: npm, promise, protractor, cucumberjs

[image][image]My scenario is to automate three sections in the same page and each section has a radio button, drop down etc..

After filling all the fields in each section I need to click Continue button and it takes a while to load.
I have successfully completed automating two sections, but when I click Continue button in the second section to navigate to the third. I am facing the below error

```
 "TypeError: doneDeferred.fulfill is not a function"
```

I have understood that it may be synchronisation issue.So, I used

```
  browser.ignoreSynchronisation=true;
```

Also, i tried to use

```
  await browser.sleep(30000).then(function() {
    console.log('Hello');
   });
```

because I thought that since its taking a while to load its not inputting the values.But strangely, it doesn't go inside the function and print the console log message.

```
   and this is the code in the debugger.js file:

    validatePortAvailability_(port) {
     if (this.debuggerValidated_) {
        return selenium_webdriver_1.promise.when(false);
     }
     let doneDeferred = selenium_webdriver_1.promise.defer();
     // Resolve doneDeferred if port is available.
     let tester = net.connect({ port: port }, () => {
        doneDeferred.reject('Port ' + port + ' is already in use. Please 
       specify ' +
            'another port to debug.');
    });
    tester.once('error', (err) => {
        if (err.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
            tester
                .once('close', () => {
                doneDeferred.fulfill(true);
            })
                .end();
        }
        else {
            doneDeferred.reject('Unexpected failure testing for port ' + 
     port + ': ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    });
    return doneDeferred.promise.then((firstTime) => {
         this.debuggerValidated_ = true;
        return firstTime;
    }, (err) => {
        console.error(err);
        return process.exit(1);
    });
```

Expected:I have pass values through sendkeys and drop down in that section and click continue button.

Actual:Its hanging in that screen and getting the above error.

I believe that the issue is with selenium webdriver promises.Can anyone help me with this?

I am still in the learning face with protractor cucumber framework.

Comment: Share your html and the complete error to give a better view on the problem.

Comment: I didn't develop a reporter and the inbuilt cucumber report is not working

Comment: not your report. Share the html of the area you are trying to automate using protractor. And the error you get in terminal when running the test

Comment: Added the 3rd section where I am automating and getting that error.Its getting stuck over there.

Comment: You have shared the code from node_modules. The problem is with your test file and not with the `node_modules`. Is your test failing in middle or the test itself does not start? Share your test file .

Comment: In the middle, Madhan.actually if you see the screenshot of the section I am automating its in a container.So, can we use frame concepts in containers?

Comment: do you know about `async ... await`? It would be much more clear if you will re-write you function using it.